# Can't get number of affected rows with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Yesterday i changed mysqli-based code to PDO. So I am very new to PDO statements. I am having problem with getting number of matched MySQL data.

I've searched for how to get number of affected rows. I encountered with 3 methods:

1. Using COUNT(*) within SQL statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah WHERE blah = :blah`
2. Using fetchAll() then count `$var = $db->fetchAll(); count($var)`;
3. Last one rowCount().

According to php manual

> **PDOStatement::rowCount()** returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

So I didn't try rowCount(). I tried first two option. Bu they didn't work. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

**Here's my code** 
that I use for whether username(or e-mail) is already registered or not.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WHERE uye_ka = :kullanici_adi";
$ka_varmi = $db_uye->prepare($sql);
$ka_varmi->bindParam(':kullanici_adi',$kullanici_adi,PDO::PARAM_STR,255);
$ka_varmi->execute();
$ka_sonuc = $ka_varmi->fetchAll();

if (count($ka_sonuc)) {
    $form_hata = true;
    $ka_ayni = true; 
    $kayit_msg[] = "Seçtiğin kullanıcı adı başka bir kullanıcı tarafından daha önceden alınmış Başka bir tane dene";
}

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM WHERE uye_e_posta = :e_posta";
$e_varmi = $db_uye->prepare($sql2);
$e_varmi->bindParam(':e_posta',$kullanici_adi,PDO::PARAM_STR,255);
$e_varmi->execute();
$e_sonuc = $e_varmi->fetchAll();

if (count($e_sonuc)) {
    $form_hata = true;
    $e_ayni = true;
    $kayit_msg[] = "Girdiğin e-posta adresi daha önceden kullanılmış. Şifreni mi unuttun ? ";
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `print_r($ka_sonuc);` after the execution to see what your result set looks like first

Comment: Even though your error is omitting table name from the query, I'm upvoting you since you are one of very, very few people who got to the method of fetching everything into an array and counting it. +1, keep up the smart approach to development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE uye_ka = :kullanici_adi
```

Select from Where actually? You need to specify a table name

```
SELECT * FROM  myTable WHERE uye_ka = :kullanici_adi
               ^
```

Same for your second query.

Comment: I can't bleive that i have struggled for hours because of that kind of problem :) . Thanks !

Comment: You know why you struggled with such a simple error? Because you didn't give importance to the power of error messages. When it was not working you could simply have tried `echo $ka_varmi->errorInfo();` first of all :) That tells everything right there